# Express middleware not picking up header despite it being sent in request

Tags: node.js, express, jwt

I have an express REST API running on my backend server. For authentication, I am using JWT's and have express middleware that picks up the access token and verifies it using the secret. Currently, the middleware is not picking up the auth_token header in the request despite it being sent. Any help is appreciated, code below.

```
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken')

function auth(req, res, next) {
    const token = req.header('auth_token');

    if (!token) {
        res.status(401).json({ msg: "No token, authorization denied" })
    } else {
        try {
            const decoded = jwt.verify(token, process.env.ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET)
            req.user = decoded

            next()
        } catch (err) {
            res.status(400).json({ msg: "Token invalid" })
        }
    }
}

module.exports = auth;
```

The request

```
:authority: api.parotta.xyz
:method: GET
:path: /api/users/userInfo
:scheme: https
accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br
accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.9
auth_token: eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1c2VySWQiOiI1ZjUxYmIwODQ2YzQyYTAwMDZmNGFiOGIiLCJpYXQiOjE1OTk0NTc5MTgsImV4cCI6MTU5OTQ1ODgxOH0.QTjfANYGQUYAhfqQzk_B0PId7pr0jMpu7fS1rIOYIcI
origin: https://www.parotta.xyz
referer: https://www.parotta.xyz/dashboard
sec-fetch-dest: empty
sec-fetch-mode: cors
sec-fetch-site: same-site
user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 13_2_3 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/13.0.3 Mobile/15E148 Safari/604.1
```

cors

```
app.use(
    cors({
        credentials: true,
        origin: process.env.ORIGIN
    })
);

ORIGIN=https://www.parotta.xyz
```

Comment: could you please include a snippet for when you are setting the header as a response too?

Comment: Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client

this is the error I am receiving in production only

Comment: Please show the client code that is sending the header.  It's possible the error is on that end of things.

Comment: ```
const response = await axios.get('https://api.parotta.xyz/api/users/userInfo', {
            headers: {
                auth_token: getAccessToken()
            }
        })
```

Comment: @jfriend00I updated the question with more information and left the client info in the comments

Comment: I think it should be `req.headers` instead of `req.header`

Comment: @Naresh the function isn't the problem... its req.header

Comment: Its working in local development but it doesn't work in production with dokku Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client

Comment: [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT] you are getting this error because you are returning the same response twice from the server.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

**I have created a middleware, and I have tested this with postman, hope this helps, edit it according to your needs**

```
const auth = async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
        const token = req.header('Authorization').replace('Bearer ', '');
        const decode = jwt.verify(token, 'xyz');
        const user = await User.findOne({
            _id: decode._id,
            'tokens.token': token //mongoose syntax
        })

        if (!user) {
            throw new Error()
        }

        req.token = token;
        req.user = user;
        next();

    } catch (error) {
        res.status(401).send({
            error: 'Please Authenticate'
        })
    }
}
```